# Wearing a baseball glove with shatnez?

Tags: halacha, shaatnez

If a baseball glove has definite shatnez, is one allowed to wear it to play baseball? Is it considered a beged and included in what the Torah meant by beged or "ya'aleh alecha"? Does the fact that the shatnez stuffing is meant to protect the hand from feeling the impact of the ball put it into a category of clothing? And even if not,what if the stuffing provides even a tiny bit more warmth than if it was not stuffed?

Comment: Can you please explain why you think it may be permitted, when it sounds like a clear *issur deoraita* to those unfamiliar with all the technicalities?

Comment: @Scimonster - see my answer _since the Shatnez in the stuffing doesn't provide any warmth to the hand (since the leather is rather thick), it [may be] permissible to wear a baseball glove that has definite Shatnez._

Answer (score 5):

The issue is not if something is considered a Beged, but if the Shatnez in it is an issue. If one gets any benefit from the Shatnez (e.g. it keeps one warm) then it's forbidden to wear, sit on and even lean on. Some of these prohibitions are Rabbinic, others are Torah prohibitions.

For example, leather covered cushions stuffed with possible Shatnez. The Kitzur - in [סימן קעו - הלכות כלאי בגדים](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0175_L2) -  brings a lenient 2nd opinion, that if the cushion is stiff and cannot wrap around the body one may sit on it.

> וּמִכָּל שֶׁכֵּן שֶׁיִזָּהֵר **שֶׁלֹּא לָשֶׁבֶת עַל הַכָּרִים, שֶׁהֵן כִּלְאָיִם** (עַיֵּן באר היטב סִימָן שא סָעִיף קטן ב). **וְיֵשׁ מַתִּירִין אֲפִלּוּ לֵישֵׁב עַל הַכָּרִים, כֵּיוָן שֶׁעֲשׂוּיִים בְּאֹפֶן שֶׁאֵינָם נִכְפָּפִים עַל צְדָדֵי הָאָדָם** (עַיֵּן פתחי תשובה בשם פנים מאירות). ‏

On the other hand, a wagon covered with a Shatnez-tarp; while one may sit under it, one may not lean against it.

> עֲגָלוֹת (קוטש, קאללעס) שׁיֵשׁ לָהֶן מִכְסֶה שֶׁהַשָׂרִים הוֹלְכִין בָּהֶן, וְיֵשׁ מֵהֶן מְחֻפּוֹת מִבִּפְנִים בְּבִגְדֵי צֶמֶר שֶׁהֵם כִּלְאַיִם, כִּי מִסְּתָמָא נִתְפְּרוּ בְּחוּטֵי פִשְתָן, **מֻתָּר לָלֶכֶת בָּהֶם, וּבִלְבַד שֶׁיִזָּהֵר שֶׁלֹּא לְהִשָּׁעֵן בַּצְּדָדִים שֶׁיֵשׁ שָׁם כִּלְאָיִם**.‏

Note that neither cushions nor tarps are a Beged.

Regarding baseball gloves:
According to [RabbiKaganoff.com](http://rabbikaganoff.com/more-on-shatnez-laws/), since the Shatnez in the stuffing doesn't provide any warmth to the hand (since the leather is rather thick), it's permissible to wear a baseball glove that has definite Shatnez.

The [hakhel](http://www.hakhel.info/archivesShatnez/ShatnezGuideNov07.pdf) site is less enthusiastic and says *Halachic opinions on this
complex issue vary widely.*

<sup>Reminder: We do not Pasken on Mi Yodeya;  ask your LOR for a practical ruling.</sup>

Comment: Isn't the protection offered by the padding considered a benefit? The padding is there to enable one to catch the baseball without fear of injury or pain. What are the operational definitions for benefit in the case of _shatnez_? Is it only protection from the elements?

Comment: @ShmuelBrown. I should have clarified that in the question, but that's one of the things I was thinking about. The shatnez is there to protect the hand from the impact. Is that a beged. And even if not, what if it provides a bit more warmth derech agav.

Comment: @MarkA. - "protect the hand from the impact" does not make it a Beged. Proof: All gloves become Tameh (Ritually unclean) except for gloves that are used to protect the hand when picking thorns - see Keilim 26:3

Comment: @ShmuelBrown - I guess _the protection offered by the padding is_ not _considered a benefit_, since the padding in cushions is permitted, even though (to put it politely) it protects your spine from impact injury while traveling.

Comment: @DannySchoemann. But cushions aren't "worn". Baseball gloves are.

Comment: @MarkA. - that may explain why there's a dispute: Do we say you are "wearing" your impact-resistance glove? Do we consider it an item of clothing? It's purely for baseball; you wouldn't consider wearing it in the snow.  OTOH it's worn like a glove.